# How to pass a JSON array object to a function from ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

We have a Node.js application and when a user hits a certain route, a JSON array  is  fetched from an  api(backend) and passed to my EJS template as an array object.

In the EJS template I have button which on click calls a Javascript function which does some computation on the JSON array object  and displays the computed value on an html DIV element . I don’t know how to send the JSON array object from the ejs template to the javascript function. I see a similar question posted in stackoverflow but i dont see any correct solution for that

The code for passing the JSON array object from node js router to ejs template looks like below . Here 'data' is the JSON array object sent to ejs file(gallery.ejs) using res.render()

```
app.get(“/getBill”, function(req, res) {


   bill(locationID,tableID, (error, billdata) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error)
                res.render("error")
            }
            else {

                var data=billdata
                res.render("gallery",{data:billdata})
            }
        })


});
```

I can access the  JSON array object ‘data ’ in my ejs file (gallery.ejs) and iterate through it and  access the  elements in the JSON array.

```
<% data.forEach(item => {%>
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
    <%=item.name%>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 text-sm-right">
    $<%=item.price/100%>
  </div>

</div>
<%});%>
```

But  I need to pass the JSON array object ‘data’  in the ejs file to a function on click of a button (see below). My goal is to access the  JSON array object 'data' inside the function  myFunction.

```
<button type="button" id="zeroperc" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="myFunction()">0%</button>
```

How can I pass the JSON array object 'data' from ejs template to the function myFunction ()?

Comment: "JSON array object" .... which is it? JSON? Array? Object?

Comment: @JaromandaX for the sake of argument, I guess an array with objects, deserialized from a json response? ^_^

Comment: seriously though, if data is JSON vs Array makes a difference to how you'd go about it

Comment: Its a JSON... how do i access the JSON inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `data` to the function argument using ejs:

```
<button type="button" id="zeroperc" class="btn btn-outline-primary"
onclick="myFunction(<%=data%>)">0%</button>
```

Also, assuming `data` is actually json, you might need to call `JSON.parse(data)` from `myFunction` before you can access it's properties.

### Update

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <%=data%>;
</script>

<button type="button" id="zeroperc" class="btn btn-outline-primary"
onclick="myFunction(data)">0%</button>
```

Comment: No this doesnt work.  i get  a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error when i try onclick="myFunction(<%=data%>)"

Comment: @vigneshd I added an update.  Hopefully that works.

Comment: if you use <%=data%> within a script tag it shows an error. Looks like <%=data%> works outside a script tag but not within a script tag.... also we can access 'data' within the ejs template just by using  <%var data=data%> but if you do  onclick="myFunction(data) you will get an error ' Uncaught ReferenceError: total is not defined'

Comment: @vigneshd can you show me the `myFunction`?  I don't use ejs often, but I can assure you that it is common practice among template languages to pass context variables to scripts in this manner.  If ejs doesn't have support for this, you might be better off using another template language.

Comment: I am just trying to pass the value to the function on click of the button and print the value inside the function but its not working. I am passing the value like this  <button type="button" id="zeroperc" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="myFunction(<%=data%>)">0%</button> and  inside the function i am trying to display the value like this <script>function myFunction(p) {
      console.log(p);}</script> .. i can also see that my Visual Studio code editor shows on an error on the line which contains onclick="myFunction(<%=data%>)" .. I assume this means that this is a syntax error.

Comment: I have done so much of the coding using ejs already...dont think its feasible to use any other template language at this point of time. I really appreciate your willingness to help me @CalebGoodman